# How to get cython to rebuild when changing h files?

Tags: cython

I have a cython wrapper of a c library and "bake" some defines into the build by generating a h header file in the setup script which i then include in my main pxd file before i include the header of the c library.
That works, but the build script doesn't seem to realize when the .h files has changed.
I have to enforce a rebuild by removing the build folder.

Is there a way to have the parts rebuild that include the changed h file ?

Comment: The answer in the duplicate isn't hugely detailed so there might be some value in adding a better one

Comment: @DavidW The answer worked for me. I could write a bit more detailed answer or just accept the other answer. Not sure what would be better.

Comment: My view is that you should accept that this is a duplicate. If you could post a slightly more detailed answer (maybe 10 lines, to give a simple example rather than a link?) in the other question that would probably end up being useful to someone else. However, you certainly aren't obliged to do that.